# Genshin impact F2P model

Tags: genshin-impact

I don't mind spending on games I love to support the devs but not to the point where your progress or how strong you are is hugely influenced by the amount you spend (FIFA FUT).

I currently play Destiny 2 and i'm ok with the seasonal model where we pay for seasons (mostly 3 months per season). But it's upto you to pay for the season pass or continue to play the F2P parts.

SO, my question is, what should be my expectation before picking up Genshin Impact.

Comment: I'm guessing that this question is being voted down as being too opinion-based.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based. This question is asking about what to expect about the F2P model in a specific game. Just because OP shared an opinion, doesn't mean answers have to be opinion based.

Comment: The way this question is worded makes it opinion-based.  If someone can edit it to ask a deterministic question, it should be reopened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You dont have to pay for anything in Genshin Impact at all. You are able to earn Primogems (the primary currency for getting new characters) at a decent enough rate as a free2player. Nothing in the game is gated by paying money, you are able to access anything and everything as F2P.

Paying money is for convenience and convenience only. You can roll the character/weapon gacha more often, and recover Resin (a currency used for collecting character/weapon progression items) faster. Your play is not hindered without these (there's tons of other activities you can do while waiting for Resin to Recharge, and Primogen is a constant flow, like I mentioned earlier)

I'm adventure Rank 40 with no shortage of things to do. Yes the main and story quests are "over" until the next update, but the world still has plenty of content.

Comment: Also of note, There is a "pity" pull system in place where after a certain number of pulls you are guaranteed a 5* character or weapon. Although, a lot of the 4* characters are as good a 5*. Most of the "gamer magazine" sources that talk about the gacha pulls neglect to mention that and give people the wrong idea. (the system is also based on individual pulls so it never hurts to do a single pull vs a 10-pull because the odds aren't better in a 10-pull)

Comment: "Nothing in the game is gated by paying money" I'm a newer player, so my information might be slightly inaccurate (or perhaps this was different at the time this answer was written), but I don't think this is 100% true. There's a set of weapons that, to my knowledge, can only be obtained by paying for the Battle Pass. They're not 5-Star weapons, so it may not be a huge deal for many players, and I can't think of anything else that can't be obtained without paying money, but it does mean there's at least one small thing behind a paywall.

Comment: @Andii it's very possible. I wrote this answer while the game was still fairly new and now no longer play it. It could be no longer correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main reasons you might want to spend money on Genshin Impact:

1. To obtain a specific character (or constellation level for a character), weapon or artefact.
2. To improve your characters, weapons and artefacts at a faster rate than the free to play systems allow.

To expand upon these:

1. Characters and weapons are obtained via a gacha system of spending wishes to obtain a random character or weapon. The chance of pulling a specific item is very low, so if you have your heart set on obtaining a certain character there is a good chance you would need to spend money on additional wishes (though there is no guarantee you will ever get a specific character unless they are the Event wish character, in which case 200 wishes will guarantee you get that character). If you don't care about which specific characters you use then you are given enough free ones to make a full party, and enough free wishes to pull a few more random characters. Note that to max out a character's constellation requires pulling the same character seven times, which is almost certainly unfeasible without monetary input or a lot of time investment.
2. After playing for some time, your limiting factor on improving items will likely be resin - you have a limit of 120 resin to spend, which regenerates at a rate of 1 per 8 minutes. Resin must generally be spent to obtain rewards such as character, weapon and talent improvement materials. If you are just playing the game for fun then this won't be a problem - you can complete all the questlines without worrying too much about your upgrades. Once you have finished all the story content the only thing currently left to do in the game from a progression standpoint is to upgrade characters and items, which requires resin, which you have in limited supply each day - but can spend money to refill. If maxing out all your upgrades as fast as possible is important to you, then you would thus need to spend money on refilling resin.